# Is there any difference between "now" and "so far" when used in the present perfect?

Tags: difference

Could you tell me if there is any difference between *now* and *so far* when used in the present perfect? For example:

> I've been to four foreign countries **now**.
>
> I've been to four foreign countries **so far**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I've been to four foreign countries now." -> Means that as of now (i.e. starting at this moment), you have been to four foreign countries. This implies that you just visited a foreign country.

"I've been to four foreign countries so far." -> Means that you have been to four foreign countries in your lifetime (i.e. you did not necessarily just visit a foreign country).

In both cases, it would be more natural to start with "So far, ..."/ "Now, ..."